# Windows 11-intermittent interruption on peripherals/lights

Tags: usb, power, peripherals, rgb

This happens at seemingly random intervals, but I usually notice it while gaming, not so much with other tasks.

First, I notice my mouse, headset and my mic stop working, then all the lights on my PC and those devices flicker. Keyboard is unaffected

Headset is plugged into a Corsair stand w/3.5mm and the stand is plugged into the PC using micro-USB 3.0 to rear I/O, mic and keyboard are also plugged into rear I/O but mouse is wireless and the adapter is plugged into the front I/O. I've tried changing around which plugs I'm using and it seems to have no effect.

I update my drivers regularly. Any and all troubleshooting tips would be helpful.

MSI B450 Carbon, Ryzen5 2600X, 1660Ti, 16gb DDR4, Corsair 750 watt PSU

Comment: Check if the computer is well-earthed. Also, some games require energetic gestures by the player that might move objects around, is that the case?

Comment: @harrymc Nothing in the case is shorting out, and I'm not jerking on the cables.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been related to the headset stand I was using. I haven't had the issue since unplugging it.